# What is this blue rectangle thing for? How do i get rid of it?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I'm new to Android Studio have no idea what I'm doing. Just hit a course on Udemy and it doesn't have that weird blue square so how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Udemy uses a old version of Android Studio

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense but how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called blueprint view. The first 3 buttons of the toolbar strip of the layout edit tab can switch between "design", "blueprint" and "design and blueprint".